# python scipy weave long integer

Tags: python, long-integer

I'm using scipy.weave to improve the performance of my python code. Basically, I have to go through a long array (1024^3,3) -i.e. an array containing 1024^3 elements, with each element having 3 entries- compute several things for each element and then fill another array.

The problem is that I get and segmentation fault when the array is larger than ~(850**3,3). The segmentation fault takes places when I try to read the value of the array at the position (a,3), where a = 715827882. Note that 3*a ~ 2^31. I have carefully explored this issue and it seems to me that I can't go through arrays with a length larger than the size of an integer variable.

In fact, this simple program

```
################################
import numpy as np
import scipy.weave as wv

def printf():

    a=3*1024**3

    support = """
          #include <iostream>
          using namespace std;
    """

    code = """
        cout << a << endl;
    """
    wv.inline(code,['a'],
              type_converters = wv.converters.blitz,
              support_code = support,libraries = ['m'])

printf()
#########################################
```

outputs -1073741824 instead of 3221225472. Which means (I think) that the variable a is taken in the c code as an integer of 32 bits, instead of 64 bits.

Does anyone know how to solve this? Of course, I can only split my array in pieces of sizes smaller than 2^31, but I found this very inefficient.

Thanks.